# Flutter: Should I specify keep-alive in my headers or use an http.Client throughout the app?

Tags: flutter, keep-alive, flutter-http

An app we have in production has a lot of http requests dealing with authorization, fetching data, and posting data to the backend. It's been reported to us that it load times were lengthy and I figured it was because of the way I was using the http package all throughout the app.

What I know according to the `http` package...

> If you're making multiple requests to the same server, you can keep open a persistent connection by using a `Client` rather than making one-off requests. If you do this, make sure to close the client when you're done.

So far, I've only used the `Client` class on our bag screen which first gets the items a user have in their cart, then *calls an endpoint for each product once*. Meaning that if a user had `N` items in their bag, the app does `N+1` calls.

I'm wondering if I should persist a connection all throughout the app lifecycle using the `http.Client` and if that's proper practice. I've also recently read about http Keep-Alive and I wonder if I should just include that header in each of my requests.